How to display all returned results but clear the state at every request?
My server callback already pre-filters the data and I want Tom Select to display all the results returned for the given query. I've tried to achieve this by setting searchField: []. However, this also keeps results of previously typed queries.
Examples:

bad: missing results:


User searches for "Zurich" or "St Gallen"
The server returns "Zürich" or "St. Gallen", but Tom Select discards those results because they do not match the typed string.
Conclusion: I want Tom Select to display all returned results.


bad: old results:


User searches for "Zurich", then "St Gallen" (typing slowly and erasing the previous search with backspace)
Results contain Zur, Zuric, Zurich, St, St Ga, St Gallen
Conclusion: I want Tom Select to only display the results of the most recent query to the server


good: what I'd need instead:


User searches for "Zurich", then "St Gallen" (typing slowly and erasing the previous search with backspace)
As soon as the user has finished typing "Zurich", the result "Zürich" is displayed.
As the user erases "Zurich" and finishes typing "St Gallen", the result "St. Gallen" is displayed.

Which combination of options allows me to cause this behavior?
Here is a minimal reproducible example:


function search(q, callback) {
  if (q === "Zürich" || q === "Zuerich") {
    callback([{
        'text': 'Zürich',
        'value': 1
      },
      {
        'text': 'Zuerich',
        'value': 2
      }
    ]);
  } else if (q === "St. Gallen" || q === "St Gallen") {
    callback([{
        'text': 'St. Gallen',
        'value': 3
      },
      {
        'text': 'St Gallen',
        'value': 4
      }
    ]);
  } else {
    callback();
  }
}

var settings = {
  load: (q, callback) => this.search(q, callback),
  searchField: []
};
new TomSelect('#tom-select-it', settings);
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<input id="tom-select-it" />
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/tom-select@2.3.1/dist/css/tom-select.css" rel="stylesheet">
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/tom-select@2.3.1/dist/js/tom-select.complete.min.js"></script>




Please add a [mcve]

I've edited accordingly

This was not trivial.
I had a go at the DOCS
I added the Diacritics and also a keyup handler for the backspace
Lastly I debounced using a throttle


let inputElement;
const handleKeyUp = (event) => {
  const query = inputElement.value.trim();
  // Clear options for each keyup to refresh results
  if (query === "") {
    // If the input is empty, close the dropdown
    tS.close();
    tS.load(query, callback => callback([])); // Pass an empty result set
  }
};
const normalizeText = (text) => text.normalize("NFD").replace(/[\u0300-\u036f]/g, "");

const search = (q, callback) => {
  q = normalizeText(q); // Normalize query input
  console.log('?', q)
  // Filter results by normalized text
  const filteredResults = results.filter(item =>
    normalizeText(item.text).includes(q)
  );

  callback(filteredResults);
}

const settings = {
  diacritics: true,
  loadThrottle: 300,
  load: function(q, callback) {
    inputElement = document.getElementById('tom-select-it-ts-control'); // add a keyup event handler for backspace
    inputElement.addEventListener('keyup', handleKeyUp);
    if (q.trim() === "") {     // Check if the query is empty
      this.clearOptions(); // Clear options
      this.refreshItems(); 
      callback([]); // Stop further processing
      return;
    }
    search(q, callback); // Call the search function with query if input is not empty
  },
  searchField: ['text']
};

let tS = new TomSelect('#tom-select-it', settings);
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<input id="tom-select-it" />
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/tom-select@2.3.1/dist/css/tom-select.css" rel="stylesheet">
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/tom-select@2.3.1/dist/js/tom-select.complete.min.js"></script>
<script>
  const results = [{
      'text': 'Zürich',
      'value': 1
    },
    {
      'text': 'Zuerich',
      'value': 2
    },
    {
      'text': 'St. Gallen',
      'value': 3
    },
    {
      'text': 'St Gallen',
      'value': 4
    }
  ];
</script>



